# Removing non-letter Characters from String leaves UTF-16 High Surrogates

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-negation

I am using the regex `[^\\p{L}]` and `java.util.regex.Matcher#replaceAll(String)` to match and remove all non-letter characters from a string. I noticed that for characters containing UTF-16 surrogates, `replaceAll()` creates a structurally invalid string (OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1).

First a working example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}]");
    System.out.println(p.matcher("abcဍ*").replaceAll(""));
  } 
}
```

The above program prints `abcဍ` as expected (ဍ is MYANMAR LETTER DDA).

Now let's test the character "" (`\uD835\uDD0D`, MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL J, Category: Letter, Uppercase [Lu]), which contains high surrogates:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String original = ""; // "\uD835\uDD0D"
    
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}]");   // try regex without negation first
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(original);
    String r1 = m1.replaceAll("");
    System.out.println("r1: " + r1);
  
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}]");  // now try regex with negation
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(original);
    String r2 = m2.replaceAll("");
    System.out.println("r2: " + r2);
    System.out.println("r2 length: " + r2.length());
    System.out.println("r2 char(0): " + (int) r2.charAt(0));

    System.out.println("original: " + original);
  } 
}
```

Output:

```
r1:                     // r1 = empty string as expected
r2: ?                   // r2 = broken string
r2 length: 1            
r2 char(0): 55349       // 0xD835 (high surrogate)
original:
```

Other examples I tested that produce structurally invalid strings:

- (`\uD801\uDCD8`), OSAGE SMALL LETTER A, Category: Letter, Lowercase [Ll]
- (`\uD806\uDECA`), PAU CIN HAU LETTER KHA, Category: Letter, Other [Lo]

Is my regex broken, or is this a bug in the Java Class Library? If this is a bug, is there a workaround?

Comment: Looks like `\p{L}` in Java regex supports both BMP and astral planes, but the construct is a placeholder for a complex pattern including alternations with multicharacter sequences, and thus, cannot be used inside a character class. `Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\P{L}");` returns what you need, right?

Answer (score 2):

In your current Java version, the problem is that `\p{L}` is a placeholder, mnemonic for a more complex pattern that includes alternatives with multicharacter sequences.

That means, the `\p{L}` pattern cannot be used inside a character class, as character classes are not meant to match *char sequences*, only *individual* chars.

Thus, you need to make sure you use it outside of a character class. Here, you can simply use the reverse Unicode category class, `\P{L}`, to match any char but a Unicode letter. The following:

```java
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\P{L}");
```

[returns what you need](https://ideone.com/YQUTV1).

In case you cannot replace  with the
reverse class, you can use an alterenation. For example, if you have `[^\d\s\p{L}]`, you can use `(?:\P{L}|[^\d\s])`.

Note that your code looks working in Java 17+ ([confirmed by user16320675](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71334622/removing-non-letter-characters-from-string-leaves-utf-16-high-surrogates/71337381#comment126090879_71334622)).

Comment: Thanks! How do you know `\p{L}` is a placeholder for a more complex pattern? Can you point me to the implementation, documentation, or a bug ticket?

Comment: @GJL I learnt it through testing. The source code is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/c46daef6edb5/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java).

Answer (score 1):

For cases like this I wrote my own utility that allows to convert any String to unicode sequence and vice-versa. Here is a sample:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html). This helps me a lot when I need to diagnose problems like yours, but also in extreme scenarios you can convert String into unicodes and modify it as codes and convert it back. It might be a workaround for you until you find better solution